# How to drop the https from urls in bibliography using biblatex and hyperref

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

I am using `biblatex` to generate a bibliography and using `hyperref` for clickable links.
I want to set a reference to a website. Let's say Ansys' one using the `@online` class.
So my .bib file would contain something like this:

```
@online{ansysTag,
    title = {ANSYS Studio},
    url = {https://ansys.com/},
    urldate = {2020-04-01}
}
```

I would like to get rid of the 'https' in the printed bibliography as it looks unaesthetic and useless. Similarly to [this problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139921/how-to-avoid-the-http-part-in-hyperrefs-url).
But if I get rid of the https in the `url` field, the link is not clickable anymore. I tried replacing it by `\href{https://ansys.com/}{ansys.com}` but this would not work either.

Is there a simpler solution ?
Thanks.

Comment: There is some code here to add the protocol internally https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/125. You only need to tell biblatex to use this command for urls.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/533812/35864 may help you.

Comment: Awesome thanks to both of you. Problem solved.

Comment: So can we close this as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/533812/35864?