# Hyphenate \texttt

Tags: xetex, line-breaking, hyphenation, urls, typewriter

Before anyone says anything, yes, of course I've seen [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44361/how-to-automatically-hyphenate-within-texttt). But, it's not what I want.

What I'm looking for is basically a way to either alter the way `\texttt` works, or a new command that works just like `\texttt` does, but, instead of hyphenating only at spaces, making it hyphenate wherever it sees fit, because in my document I have things that don't contain any sort of dashes, and they're just really long randomly-generated strings of letters and numbers, so, they won't get hyphenated with that solution. I don't care how the text gets hyphenated, I just don't want it to overfull.

Why I want this? Well, I am using a command that takes my links, and then it strips them of any protocol info (`http(s)://`) or `www`, and shows them that way inside the compiled document, but keeps them functionally the same (when they get clicked on inside the PDF). The command comes from [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/645140/253842):

```tex
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\clearurl}[1]{
    \tl_set:Nn \parsed_url {#1}
    \regex_replace_all:nnN {.*:\/\/(?:www.)?(.*[^\/])\/?} {\1} \parsed_url
    \href{#1}{\texttt{\parsed_url}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: the url package (used by hyperref) has standard listto say where line breaking can happen, xurl package sets that to allow breaking anywhere

Comment: Yes. But, as you can see, I am not using `\url`, I am using something that transforms links into nicely-formatted `\href`-s

Comment: sure but you can use `\href` to make the link with the full url and use \path` (ie`\url` wihout the linking) to make the link text

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You're telling me that I should, on line 8 in the code I pasted in the question, replace `\texttt` with `\path`, and then use the `xurl` package? That doesn't work, it transforms all the links in the document in just `\parsed_url`, meaning it doesn't actually parse that command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exploit `xurl`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xurl}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\clearurl}{m}
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__clearurl_url_tl {#1}
    \regex_replace_all:nnN {.*:\/\/(?:www.)?(.*[^\/])\/?} {\1} \l__clearurl_url_tl
    \clearurl_print:nV { #1 } \l__clearurl_url_tl
  }

\tl_new:N \l__clearurl_url_tl
\cs_new_protected:Nn \clearurl_print:nn
  {
    \href{#1}{\nolinkurl{#2}}
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clearurl_print:nn { nV }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\clearurl{https://www.google.it/books/edition/Mirifici_Logarithmorum_Canonis_Construct/VukHAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=mirifici+logarithmorum&pg=PT1&printsec=frontcover}

\end{document}
```

[image]